# Nativescript : Preparing "Install Google Repository"

Tags: android, firebase, nativescript

It's been 4 hours project building is stuck at `Preparing "Install Google Repository"`, I have nativescript-plugin-firebase plugin installed can't build my project. It works fine without firebase plugin. Any help

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? You might have to set up the gradle config to work properly. Also it is possible the repository servers have died.

Comment: Waiting for 4 hours :), you got more patience that me my friend. Definitely there is an issue with your connection to the firebase servers, check your connectivity as suggested above.

Comment: Yeah went out after starting :), I think problem is with google repository it's not able to install google repository, I tried Installing google repository from yaourt aur package but no use.:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tns can't `"Install Google Repository"` then you can try to install that from `Android Studio`. To do that go to **Android Studio > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools** and then install `Support Repository`. Now just go and rebuild your NativeScript app.